# Angular 8 how to skip validation for textbox which is not visible

Tags: angular

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm"  >
   <div class="form-group" *ngIf="isHidden">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!userForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  isHidden:boolean=false;
  title = 'Children';
  userForm: FormGroup;
  user: any = {
    firstName: ''

  };
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': [this.user.firstName, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

}
```

I am implementing reactive form angular validation If I am hide the text box so how can i skip validation
for particular text box which is not visible in my form

If my text box is visible my validation should work

means if isHidden=true validation should not work 
      if ishidden =false validation should work

Comment: If it can be hidden then it should not be `required` IMO.

Comment: understand but if its visible in that case I want to apply required validation

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to add/remove validator:

```
 checkValidator() {
    const firstNameControl = this.userForm.controls["firstName"];

    if (this.isHidden) {
      firstNameControl.clearValidators();
    } else {
      firstNameControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    }
    firstNameControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-wmu8qq?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: For me it's better **disable" the FormControl (In this case is simple because it's only one validator).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this could be to re-create the form instance every time, the value of 'isHidden' changes.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.isHidden !== undefined) {
        this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'firstName': [this.user.firstName, isHidden ? [] : [Validators.required]]
        });
    }
}
```

But beware, the form instance will be re-created on every change in `isHidden`.